# Scrollview's last bottom contents hidden by the bottom navigation view

Tags: java, xml, android-layout, kotlin

Hi coders I have a constraint layout, in it is a bottom navigation view
a tool bar on top and a scrollview which has lots of buttons going down vertically.
The problem is that the scrollview's last buttons are hiding behind the bottom navigation view after I scroll all the way to bottom how can this be solved
On the actual code there are plenty of buttons in scrollview through here I add only a few here.

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:background="#ffffff"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">
<include 
    android:id="@+id/tutorialsinclude"
    layout="@layout/app_bar_main"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    
    />
<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/tutorialsinclude"
    android:id="@+id/webtut">

    <LinearLayout
        
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        >
        <Button
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="web "
            android:id="@+id/tutorialsButton1"/>
        
            <Button
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Tutorials 1 "
            android:id="@+id/tutorialsButton1"/>
    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
      <android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView
        android:id="@+id/navigationbb"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="0dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="0dp"
        android:background="#ffffff"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:menu="@menu/navigation" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

[image: As you can see in this image the last button is hidden by the bottom navigation view and I can't scroll further up to reveal the button]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set constraint to bottom of scrollview to top of bottom navigation view and set height as 0dp which will make height to match the constraint

```
<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/tutorialsinclude"

    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/navigationbb"

    android:id="@+id/webtut">
```

Comment: Thank you so much I combined your answer and that of @Yasan's answer my layout came out perfect

Answer (score 2):

You can just put a footer in the end to fix this issue. Just make a `View` below the last button. Something like this:

```
 <View android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="32dp" />
```

You just have to adjust the height to make it work for your layout. Also, you really shouldn't manually put all these buttons in a `scrollView`. should use a `RecyclerView` instead.

Comment: Best answer for me since I am using scrollview and that is only for the fragment,  I have no way getting constraints of activity layout from fragment and don't want to.  All other things like add layout_behavior did not work.  Easiest was add some space...!